# url not working in case of web services

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to access the webservice I created through a URL as listed below:
 `http://localhost:8080/myProjectName/services` inside eclipse, but its showing me 404 error, can somebody explain why? Actually I am creating a web service provider and I am using TomCat 7.0,  apache-cxf-3.0.3, JDK 7.I made 3 packages inside src folder of a Dynamic Web Project, and inside package com.supc.services; created 1 class and used it as a web service.WSDL is creating without any error, when I try to run my project 404 error occurs, but when I try to access services using the URL mentioned above, I also get 404 error.

Comment: There are many reasons why this could happen but without any background info this question cant be answered

Comment: @Reimeus, i edited the question can u now take a look and help me please.

Comment: 404 means that the page was not found on the server. I would check in the server logs if your request arrived and what error it caused.

Comment: @Max Zoom `tomcat7-stderr.2015-02-03` file is empty

Comment: I would check catalina.out or the latest log file.